# Raw SQL insert with Korma

Tags: postgresql, clojure, korma, sqlkorma

I want to execute following raw SQL with Korma:

```
k/exec-raw
 ["INSERT INTO events ?, VALUES ? ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET title = EXCLUDED.title;" [keys values]]
```

with params equal to:

```
keys (str "(" (keys->str res) ")")
values (str "(" (serialize (merge res) ", ") ")" )
```

The both evaluate to correct strings and work in repl.

But in runtime i have following error in psql console:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1" at character 20
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO events $1, VALUES $2 ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET title = EXCLUDED.title
```

Can't figure out what's the problem. Anybody have ever done insert with Korma?

PostgreSQL 9.5 + Korma 0.4.2

Comment: Parameters don't work like that, you can't suply parts of sql (or column names for that matter) as a parameter.

Comment: Could you please go in some more details?

Answer (score 1):

Only values can be used as parameters in a prepared statement. So to make it work:

```
INSERT INTO events (column) VALUES (?)
```

If you want to work it like you do you have to prepare the sql string yourself and make sure you don't have an sql injection.
Please see the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html)